# I am having lots of trouble trying to get light to shine through a window

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, glass

I cannot figure out why the light won't shine through the window in my .blend file (linked [here](https://www69.zippyshare.com/v/XRry1OGe/file.html)).

I've made the glass transparent using the BDSF Transparent Shader. On top of this, all materials are allowing transparent shadows.

The only thing that works is if I uncheck "Cast Shadows" on the light material. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in your Glass material, if I make it simple and plug it into the *Surface* socket of the *Output* node, it works, so maybe plug this way and revise the node organization:

[image]

Comment: Ugh, I'm an idiot and didn't realize I left the plug on volume and not surface. Thank you so much!! 

By the way, I noticed you simplified things, and it worked even better. The module set up you saw me using was from a Blender Guru tutorial, any reason why it might not have been working?

Comment: well to say the truth I didn't try to decrypt the node organization, there must be something that doesn't work into it, he must have some reasons to do it this way but anyway you can do glass with only these nodes